# A string() as columns for SQL table

Tags: sql, arrays, vb.net, string

I have a csv file that I read in and I create it into a string(), now I want to input all of these into an SQL table.
It should become something like this:
TIME  string(0)  string(1) string(2) ...

How would I go about this in `vb.net`, I usually just use a small loop for stuff like this but I don't think that'll work since it's an SQL commands.

example:

`"        dim sqlcreatetable As String = _`

```
    "USE MainDB1" & vbCrLf & _

    "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE Name = 'logging' AND TYPE = 'u')" & vbCrLf & _

    "BEGIN" & vbCrLf & _

    "DROP TABLE MainDB1.dbo.logging" & vbCrLf & _

    "END" & vbCrLf & _

    "Create Table logging (TIME NVarchar(20) NOT NULL,"
    For i As Integer = 1 To aantaltags
        If (i = aantaltags) Then
            sqlcreatetable += csvtagssplit(3 * i - 2) & ") nvarchar(20) NOT NULL)"
        Else
            sqlcreatetable += csvtagssplit(3 * i - 2) & ") NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,"
        End If
    Next
    Dim dbConnection As New SqlCommand(sqlcreatetable, connection)
    connection.Open()
    dbConnection.ExecuteNonQuery()
    connection.Close()</code>
```

The size of the array is variable so I can't just make it one oversized line.

Comment: Do you want table's column as per number of strings?

Comment: The amount of columns will be the amount of strings in the array+1. Sorry if it's not completely clear what I'm trying to say English  is not my native language.

Comment: Can you give your csv file data on pastie.org or paste here some of the data? So I can get idea how to perform task.

Comment: What The program will end up doing is logging data from an OPC server to a SQL database. I can export the taglist of the OPC server to an scv file. That I import in my program, remove all the useless stuff that's in there. Then what remains (in a string()) should be imported as "titles" of the columns into a table on the sql server. The reason I do this is so that they can just import the new csv file if they want to log more stuff then initially intended and it stays somewhat user friendly. If they add a new csv file a new table will be created. I hope this clarifies what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Where is the CSV data? I am not able to see it

Comment: I don't have it with me right now. It'll be something like this: "I1.0", "Description1", "short", "I.1.1", "description2", "short",... I turn that into a string and I'll probably end up taking out the description part that'll end up at the top of the collumn. Just to clarify I won't be updating the data from the csv. It's only there to create the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make Create Table string like below:

```
Dim objConn As New SqlConnection("Server=<servername>;uid=<userid>;pwd=<password>;database=<dbaname>")

Dim csvStr as String  //Suppose It has Whole CSV file as a string
Dim csvWithoutQuotes As String = csvStr.Replace("""",""); //I am assuming that csv's any string doesn't have comma
Dim csvStrArrayOfOneLine() As String = csvWithoutQuotes.split(vbCrLf);
Dim csvStrArray() As String = csvStrArrayOfOneLine(0).split(","); 
Dim csvStrLength as Integer = csvStrArray.Length

Dim cmdString as string = "Create Table logging (TIME NVarchar(20) NOT NULL,"

For i As Integer = 0 To csvStrLength 
If ( i = csvStrLength ) Then
    cmdString += "log(" & i.ToString & ") NVarChar(20) NOT NULL)"
Else 
    cmdString += "log(" & i.ToString & ") NVarChar(20) NOT NULL,"
End If
Next
objConn.Open()
Dim objCmd As New SqlCommand(cmdString, objConn)
objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I am not a vb.net programmer, but I have tried my best to satisfy your answer. If is there any error;Let me know.

Comment: You can give reply as comment for my answer so I can get idea it is working or have some error. Be cooperative.

Comment: Let me edit the OP to give you more of an idea what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I get an SQL error, there is an incorrect syntax near '1'. Now there isn't any 1s in the code so my variable is probably doing something wrong. I made a csv to test it after all the magic it turned into a string() like this (0)=test 1 (1)= Description 1 (2)= value 1 (3)=test 2 ,...  Would you happen to know what I did wrong?

Comment: @user2376356, actually your csv contain string with quotes like "abc","xyz" now it has already quotes and In vb.net we define string with quotes so I was also thinking how to preserver csv quotes and I don't know. I think csv quotes creating problem.

Comment: Ya that's why I used *Dim csvWithoutQuotes As String = csvStr.Replace("""","");* I don't have .net installed in my system right now so I am not able to check it out. But I think it should work.

Comment: "test 1, Description 1, value 1" & vbCrLf & "test 2, Description 2, value 2" & vbCrLf & "test 3, Description 3, value 3" those are the unsplit values, I removed the "s a while back. So it's something else.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/KJATjjWb that's the unsplit data. -  (0) "test 1" String
  (1) " Description 1" String
  (2) " value 1 " String
  (3) "test 2" String
  (4) " Description 2" String
  (5) " value 2 " String
  (6) "test 3" String
  (7) " Description 3" String
  (8) " value 3 " String
  (9) "" String
this is the array the last "" is there sadly because there I also split at the end of the line.

Comment: Hey I have updated my answer. I forget to take 1st line only. I was taking whole file. Pardon me.

Comment: Concentrate of *Dim csvStrArrayOfOneLine() As String = csvWithoutQuotes.split(vbCrLf);
Dim csvStrArray() As String = csvStrArrayOfOneLine(0).split(",");*

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I'm trying to do. I hope this clears some things up: http://pastebin.com/D58m2Rxg

Comment: @user2376356 In *sqlcreatetable += csvtagssplit(3 * i - 2) & ") * you are closing the tag but there is no matching tag. updated code: http://pastebin.com/qZSkqEjQ

Comment: While that is indeed stupid it didn't fix the incorrect syntax.

Comment: I understand now, the name has to be one word. And it isn't because there is a space between description and 1. I'll have to check if this is actually an issue or not once I get the list tomorrow. Thanks for all the help, I can always end up replacing all the spaces with "_" to fix the problem.

Comment: *Description 1* is problem. Column name can't have space.

Comment: I'd give you an upvote but I can't. Thanks a ton. One last question ,now the it's _Description_1 any way to fix the _ in the front?

Comment: It's okie. My answer is helping you out is the best thing for me..take Left(STRING, 1) if it is _ take RIGHT(STRING, STRING.LENGTH -1). I don't know exact function syntax so pls look out for that. else logic is perfect.

Comment: One more question that isn't really related. If I want to write data to the sql server on the hour and at half past the hour. Would I just use a timer that checks every second whether it's time to execute the command or not. or are there ways that are more light weight?

Comment: It would be best if you post a new question. Might be others can help you out. Coz I am not vb.net programmer.

Comment: No I'm going to write data to it on the hour and half past. So not at 35 past. As is I'm thinking If TimeString = (47 values of 00:00:00 to 23:30:00)

Comment: I think I will not be able to answer you. Post new question. This is somewhat unknown for me.